# Wordpress Admins or Roles per Page

Tags: admin

I would like to define an admin that has Administrator rights to everything - thats of course possible, its the default functionality. then i would also like to create an admin (or role) that can only edit and see certain PAGES in the backend. i have gone through many plugins but i can't seem to find this functionality anywhere!
any ideas?
thanks!
mark

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend 2 plugins:

- [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/): This plugin allows you create new roles and adjust their capabilities.
- [Hide Admin Menu](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-hide-admin-menu-plugin/290744): This plugin allows you hide menu items based on user role. You just need to select which menu items will be hidden for curtain roles.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one plugin that I know it does that right now. It's called Press Permit, and you will need the Pro (paid) version if you want the functionality of editing specific pages. I am still looking for another alternative as the UI of this plugin is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any plugin that can do what you want.

You didn't cited any programming possibility, but if you want to scratch a plugin to do this exactly as you want, you might look at the [user levels](http://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels) and [admin hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Starting from there, you'll have to apply rules and modify the admin query for getting pages.

Perhaps, maybe the built-in user permissions (author and editor) can already do that, as authors can't edit things created by other users.

Hope it helps... somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/ its a great plugin I use on all the sites I do. You can leave admin as default but specify exactly what you want and dont want all other users to see. So you can hide everything but the pages section for all editors if you wanted.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Role Scoper (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) is another option.

You can set permissions on a page or post basis, if you like. It is something I am looking into using for some of our forms. Has anyone compared it with adminimize and other similar plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I share your frustration, I've searched a fair amount and was a little surprised. Most user role management plugins only give you the control to edit users' permissions on an entire post_type basis (i.e. managing the ability to edit ALL or No pages, posts, etc) or control permissions to edit plugins and settings.

I have found two that specifically manage users' permissions to edit specific pages but both require you to purchase their pro versions to have this ability

- [Press Permit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/press-permit-core/)
- [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).
- Role Scoper had this option and it was free but its development was discontinued in 2016 and its author referred people to use Press Permit.

There is also [Capability Manager Enhanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/) and [advanced access manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) but the major disadvantage is that you cannot enable more than 1 user to have edit permissions to a specific page.